# TypeScript generics - expect type argument to be enum, and refer to its keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a reusable multistep wizard component in react and typecript.  The wizard would require certain values to be passed to it through a react context object.  The value of that context object must follow a general pattern:

```
export interface WizardContextValues {
  currentStep: number;
  setStep: (stepState: number) => void;
  completedSteps: { [key: string]: boolean };
  setCompletedSteps: (state: { [key: string]: boolean }) => void;
  disabledSteps: { [key: string]: boolean };
}
```

You can see that for `completedSteps` and `disabledSteps`, I am expecting an object.  But I'd like to constrain this a bit more.  Let's say for a specific wizard, I have an enum of steps:

```
export enum UploadWizardSteps {
  UPLOAD_FILE,
  GIVE_DETAILS,
  CONFIRMATION
}
```

I would like to actually make `WizardContextValues` generic, such that it takes the steps enum as an argument.  Something like this:

```
export interface WizardContextValues<Steps> {
  currentStep: number;
  setStep: (stepState: number) => void;
  completedSteps: { [key in Steps]: boolean };
  setCompletedSteps: (state: { [key in Steps]: boolean }) => void;
  disabledSteps: { [key in Steps]: boolean };
}

type UploadWizardContext = WizardContextValues<UploadWizardSteps>
```

I get an error when trying to use `key in Steps`, saying `Type 'Steps' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'. Type 'Steps' is not assignable to type 'symbol'`

This sort of makes sense, as when defining the generic `interface WizardContextValues<Steps>`, typescript has no idea that `Steps` is an enum and that its keys can be referenced using the `key in` operator.

### [typescript playground showing the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKpgDYQIYAmA6gJYBeeUBAyjMGAM5wDeAsAFByYAKAMgPIBBACIB9AGIBJXgFEANBy4BxSQDUZo4TIAqg6dQWc4AYX4A5KQCUAsoO2TzHAL4cOJRHSgAzPAGNgcKQUVMYQHqAwqnjYyMAMADy09AwAfCyKcL7IUFBIMElgAFxwKKgARsBQANwZDMD5dEVwABQMjbR4dMWlFVAAlHAAvGkAbhAkBDVGvhCoOPXANI0MxcxwANoA1sAAnnDucAUMALrFZRAQ2MB4iHBOU1x1MKFzV3RLycWtMJ3AqxvbPYHI6nODnS7XW5OAbDOBjCYPOAEEgMPBlK4fRj-La7fa3EFnC5XG53KYudgcGA7MABLC4QhBSgEULhEDwQaBchMll0NlRGJxeJ0-DELlUI4pIA)

How can I create this generic type such that certain properties of `UploadWizardContext` must be objects whose keys are values of `UploadWizardSteps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this is currently written, TypeScript has no way of knowing anything about `Steps` when it's used inside `WizardContextValues`. You could presumably pass anything in there as the type, including things that can't be used as keys.

You can solve this by restricting the types that can be used for `Steps` using `extends`.

By default, TypeScript enums use `number` values, though you could use the wider `string | number | symbol` type to fully reflect what's usable for object properties:

```
export enum UploadWizardSteps {
  UPLOAD_FILE,
  GIVE_DETAILS,
  CONFIRMATION
}

export interface WizardContextValues<Steps extends string | number | symbol> {
  currentStep: number;
  setStep: (stepState: number) => void;
  completedSteps: { [key in Steps]: boolean };
  setCompletedSteps: (state: { [key in Steps]: boolean }) => void;
  disabledSteps: { [key in Steps]: boolean };
}

type UploadWizardContext = WizardContextValues<UploadWizardSteps>
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgDgGwPYEMAmB1AlgLxQJzQGUAXYOAZygG8BYAKClgAUAZAeQEEARAfQDEAkqwCiAGgZMA4oIBqI3txEAVTsKITGUAMLsAckIBKAWU7LB%20zQF8GDLCDL4AZigDGwKNjyFtSB8AAPElkUBDBgCgAeUnIqQLIQNCoKEnx7AHMoAB8ocAgAI2B8bKgKAE8CpAQAPhpJKFcwfHxQEhi4AC5cyEL8AG56imA2sk6oAAoU8lIUMi683oBKKABeWoA3JCw0Aa1XJAhEYeBiUYou6igAbQBrYDKoeyh2igBdLvykKuAUECgrXZMIYkXyHBDHU6xLqTEizYAXa53B5PF7vKCfb6-f7LNZQTbbQFQNBYCgofLgyGUBG3e6PP6oj5fcFYgEMGz0BgkMpwDzwZDoLwENC%20fxBVaeXBCkVkIIhMIRSJ81CYSWEF7VIA)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: Btw, there is a built in type for property type `PropertyKey`, so you dont need to use `string | number | symbol`. You can do: `Steps extends PropertyKey`

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip, I didn't know about that.